# KDE Plasma Colors are not changing correctly

Tags: linux, kde, gtk, gtk3

I installed KDE Plasma Version 5.12.9 on Linux Mint 19.3
It's working fine excpet the colors

After a few problems with themes I managed to get them working, but not all colors are correct.
The System Settings Windows is a QT5 window themed
but some colors like the text in this window is not reading the correct color

In this Image you can see the Window Text set to White, but in the System Settings Window next to it the Text on the Window is black
[image: Colors messed]
[image: The title is white but other texts are black]

Comment: maybe that is not "Window text"

Comment: Well, Linux Mint dropped its KDE version. Perhaps, when you "installed KDE Plasma Version 5.12.9", something is still missing? In a normal system such Kubuntu, all colors work just fine and one doesn't need to use `Palette Editor` or `qt5ct`. System settings has a "Colors" widget that handles things. It's just below "Workspace Theme" in your screenshot. Did you try it?

Comment: @jsotola yes, you are probably right, but I have changed all colors on qt5 settings, they change every thing except those texts!

Comment: @DKBose Yes Indeed, It was missing things and the colors were worst, I've installed something else that I don't rember and that almost worked fine, except those colors I've mentioned!